# How to do this kind of query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

suppose I have s mongo database:

```
[
    {
        name: tom,
        tags: ["a","b"]
    }
    {
        name: lee,
        tags: ["b","c", "d"]
    }
    {
        name: jack,
        tags: ["c","d"]
    }
]
```

I want to find the object which the tags include `b`, like the above `tom` and `lee`

so what query sentence I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({ tags: "b" })
```

Simple as that.